# Set/Add subfigure counter

Tags: numbering, subfloats, subcaption

I need to change the counter for the second figure and both subfigures. For figure it works but not with subfigures. tnx a lot

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \caption{new}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{subfigure A}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{subfigure B}
        \end{subfigure}     \caption{new}
    \end{figure}

    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}    %works
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{+2}         %doesnt work

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{subfigure should be c instead of a, addtocounter for subfigure doesnt work}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{subfigure should be d instead of b, addtocounter for subfigure doesnt work}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{number should like the figure before, addtocounter for figure works}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to put your addition to the `subfigure` counter *inside* the first subfigure:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \caption{new}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{subfigure A}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{subfigure B}
        \end{subfigure}     \caption{new}
    \end{figure}
   \addtocounter{figure}{-1}    %works
   \addtocounter{subfigure}{2}  % doesn't work here
    \begin{figure}[htb]
           \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
           \addtocounter{subfigure}{2} % works here
            \caption{ subfigure should be c instead of a, addtocounter for subfigure doesnt work}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{subfigure should be d instead of b, addtocounter for subfigure doesnt work}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{number should like the figure before, addtocounter for figure works}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: hi alan, tnx - works fine!

Comment: Added note: Although subfigure environments are effectively minipage environments, if minipage is used, the subfigure counter will not function.